# How to use preg_replace regex for turning * into HTML

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have paragraphs of texts with this kind of markup in them:

```
text1 *text2* text3
```

I need to turn them into

```
text1 <strong>text2</strong> text3
```

I tried this code

```
$pattern = '~\*(.*)\*~'; 
$replacement = '<strong>\1</strong>'; 
$str = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
```

It doesn't recognize the second, closing asterisk. The closing strong" html tag only appears at the next (third) asterisk much later in the same text.

What am I missing?

**Update**: Avinash's pattern worked for the issue, but here is a related one

I used the same pattern (the first of the  two) to replace underscores with  tags. But the same paragraphs included images with syntax like `<img src="/my_image.jpg" width="700" height="300">` How do I avoid this regex turning those underscores? (The width/height numbers vary, not constant.)

E.g. from a text like this

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <img src="/my_image.jpg" width="700" height="300">  adipiscing elit. _Fusce pharetra_ a dui nec interdum.
```

I would like to get this

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <img src="/my_image.jpg" width="700" height="300">  adipiscing elit. <em>Fusce pharetra</em> a dui nec interdum.
```

Comment: it works for me http://regex101.com/r/vW2pQ7/8. Your regex will work  if there are exactly two double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the quantifier `?` after `*` which was present inside the capturing group to do a shortest possible match,

```
$pattern = '~\*(.*?)\*~';
```

OR

```
$pattern = '~\*[^*]*\*~';
```

Comment: aargh, I used the same pattern (the first of your two) to replace underscores with <em> tags. But the same paragraphs included images with syntax like <img src="/my_image.jpg" width="700" height="300"> How do I avoid this regex turning those underscores? (The width/height numbers vary, not constant.)

Comment: add the above comment in your question and describe what's your input and the expected output.

Comment: Thanks Avinash, I tried the regex you posted, but couldn't figure out how to incorporate with the rest of my code. I updates the topic opener with a detailed version of my second question.